# Powershell SharePoint Kerberos New-SPWebApplication

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, kerberos

Don't work - when creating a new site, is Integrated Security - NTLM:

```
$ap = (New-SPAuthenticationProvider)
$ap | fl
$ap.DisableKerberos = $false
$ap | fl *
Start-Sleep -s 10

New-SPWebApplication -Name $WebAppName -Port $WebAppPort -HostHeader $WebAppHostHeader -URL ("http://" + $WebAppHostHeader) -ApplicationPool $WebAppAppPool -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount $WebAppAppPoolAccount) -DatabaseName $WebAppDatabaseName -DatabaseServer $WebAppDatabaseServer –AuthenticationProvider $ap -AuthenticationMethod Kerberos
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$AP = New-SPAuthenticationProvider -UserWindowsIntegratedAuthentication
$AP | ft
$AP.DisableKerberos - $false
$AP.update
$AP | ft
$AppPoolAccount - Get-SPManagedAccount | where {$_.UserName -eq "domain\apppoolaccount"} 
$AppPoolAccount | ft -AutoSize
New-SPWebApplication -Name "MySPWebApp" -ApplicationPool "SPWebAppPool" -    ApplicationPoolAccount $AppPoolAccount -HostHeader "myspwebapp.domain.com" -Url http://myspwebapp.domain.com" -Port 80 -AuthenticationMethod Kerberos -AuthenticationProvider $AP
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$ap = New-SPAuthenticationProvider -UseWindowsIntegratedAuthentication
$ap.DisableKerberos = $false
New-SPWebApplication -Url http://localhost -Port 80  -ApplicationPool "Sharepoint 80" -AuthenticationMethod Kerberos -ApplicationPoolAccount "qatc\spadmin" -Name test -AuthenticationPovider $ap -AuthenticationMethod "Kerberos"
```